# How to remove unwanted padding under React Native Text component?

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to make a text component with a colour background and very thin padding. Like this:

[image]

However, the RN Text component has some sort of extra padding at the bottom that I don't know how to remove (and I don't know what this kind of text padding is called).

I tried setting lineHeight to the same as the fontSize, setting negative padding and margin, but the padding is always there.

Here is what I get:

`fontSize: 50, lineHeight: 50`

[image]

`fontSize: 50, lineHeight: 40`

[image]

**This is happening on both iOS and Android. How to remove it???**

This is my text component for reference:

```
<Text style={{
    backgroundColor: someDarkGreen;
    color: cyan;
    fontSize: 50;
    lineHeight: 50;
    textTransform: uppercase;
    fontWeight: bold;
    paddingHorizontal: 10;
    alignSelf: flex-start;
    marginBottom: 30;
    marginLeft: 30;
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

I still don't have a "clean answer" for my question, but since it's continuously getting upvotes I'll share my workaround.

I wrap the `<Text>` in a `<View>`, and put the background style on the View. Then I `translateY` the Text so it appears centered on the View background:

```
<View
  style={{
    backgroundColor: 'purple',
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    height: 50, // <------------------------- adjust background height here
  }}
>
  <Text
    style={{
      color: 'pink',
      fontSize: 50,
      lineHeight: 50,
      textTransform: 'uppercase',
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      alignSelf: 'flex-start',
      transform: [{ translateY: 5 }], // <-----  adjust text position here
    }}
  >
    Hello
  </Text>
</View>
```

*Note: Using `marginTop: 5` instead of `transform: [{ translateY: 5 }]` to adjust the Text position also works, **as long as the View has a fixed height**.*

This allows to have the thin vertical padding effect I was looking for when I originally posted the question. It looks nice on both iOS and Android:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late to answer, But maybe helpful for the new one..

Adding  **lineHeight:30/20;** is the key

```html
<Text style={{
    backgroundColor: someDarkGreen;
    color: cyan;
    fontSize: 50;
    lineHeight: 50;
    textTransform: uppercase;
    fontWeight: bold;
    paddingHorizontal: 10;
    alignSelf: flex-start;
    marginBottom: 30;
    marginLeft: 30;
    lineHeight:30;
  }}
/>
```

Happy coding